# value of parameter cannot be used as a constant c++

Tags: c++, parameters, int, mergesort

```
void merge(vector<Flight>& data, int low, int high, int mid, string criteria)
{
int i, j, k, temp[high - low + 1];
...
```

The error that comes up is "the value of parameter "high" (declared at line 100) cannot be used as a constant". I haven't managed to find an appropriate answer to this question online.

Comment: You are trying to use `high` as array length in a declaration. As the compiler tells you, that's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`high - low + 1` needs to be a *compile time evaluable constant expression* in C++. (C++ does not support *variable length arrays*.)

And that isn't, so the compiler issues a diagnostic.

The simple solution is to use a `std::vector<int>` as the type for `temp`.

Comment: like this: 
`vector <Flight>* temp = new vector<Flight>[high - low + 1];`?

Comment: Almost, but drop the pointer type. There's no need.

Comment: if I drop the pointer type, I get: "no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::vector<Flight, std::allocator<Flight>> *" to
"std::vector<Flight, std::allocator<Flight>>"".

Comment: The vector type needs to be an `int`, in order to match what you want for `temp`. i.e. `std::vector<int> temp(high - low + 1);`

Comment: I made a mistake in the OP. I've changed the type of temp, because I'm going to transfer something from it to `vector<Flight> data` later on in the code, which means that I need it to be a `vector<Flight>` instead of a `vector<int>`.

Comment: `std::vector<Flight> temp(high - low + 1);` will work, so long as `Flight` has the required constructors.